Test timing out waiting for click when using Playwright
I am having trouble with my test not working when using playwright.
After I run npm i playwright i proceed to create a new file called 'record1demo.spec.js' in my tests folder. I then run npx playwright codegen to create a test by clicking through elements. After I have created my new test, I run npx playwright test ./tests/record1demo.spec.js --project chromium --headed.
My test fails at:
await page.locator('#shop-sku-list-item-4678663').getByRole('link', { name: 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra' }).click(); There is a small red arrow pointing to .click() in my traceback at line 8.
I am not sure what the issue is. I am able to see the sku # that is referenced but my test fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If anymore information is needed to solve this issue I will do so. Thank you!
Objective:

Go to bestbuy.com
Search 'xbox'
Click on 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra Wireless Controller with charge dock, 30-hour battery designed for Xbox Series X|S, Windows PC, Android - Black'
Add 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra' to my cart.
When sideview cart pops up I want to click 'Go to cart'
When I am in my cart I want to add a quantity of 3 controllers.
After I want to click the yellow button to the right 'checkout'
After being redirected to new page, I want to 'continue as guest'

My code:
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.bestbuy.com/');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('What can we help you find').click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('What can we help you find').fill('xbox');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('What can we help you find').press('Enter');
  await page.locator('#shop-sku-list-item-4678663').getByRole('link', { name: 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add to Cart' }).click();
  await page.getByTestId('footer-wrapper').getByRole('button', { name: 'Go to Cart' }).click();
  await page.getByLabel('Item Quantity').selectOption('3');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Checkout', exact: true }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Continue as Guest' }).click();
});

My traceback:
Error: locator.click: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - waiting for locator('#shop-sku-list-item-4678663').getByRole('link', { name: 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra' })

   6 |   await page.getByPlaceholder('What can we help you find').fill('xbox');
   7 |   await page.getByPlaceholder('What can we help you find').press('Enter');
>  8 |   await page.locator('#shop-sku-list-item-4678663').getByRole('link', { name: 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra' }).click();
     |                                                                                                                 ^
   9 |   await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add to Cart' }).click();
  10 |   await page.getByTestId('footer-wrapper').getByRole('button', { name: 'Go to Cart' }).click();
  11 |   await page.getByLabel('Item Quantity').selectOption('3');

Test Steps:
locator.click(#shop-sku-list-item-4678663 >> internal:role=link[name="Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra"i])— record1demo.spec.js:8


Firstly, I don't think your locator '#shop-sku-list-item-4678663' is stable. It doesn't appear at all in the page when I manually browse the page. If there is only one element with a role of link and name of "Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra" on the page, you could just remove the above locator and go with await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Turtle Beach - Stealth Ultra' }).click();. Generally speaking you should aim for less complex locators as long as you can be sure they are unique on the page.
Secondary to that I think the page loads lazily, over time and possibly also as you scroll, so depending on your network conditions and site performance it could time out on that basis.
